# YetAnotherForum Customization - what ascx page being used for displaying forum topic?

Tags: yetanotherforum

YetAnotherForum 1.9.55 Customization , WindowsXpSp2

When user clicks on particular topic from the Last Forum Topic page or other page, he/she will be directed to details of topic(as below). I could not understand what ascx page being used for this page, I want to set Anonymous instead of User Name on this page(Topic details page).

I did post this query on YAF's customization forum but did not get any response so far.
[YAFForumLink](http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/yaf_postsm53672_Annonymous-User-Name-on-ForumLastPost-and-Topic-Page.aspx#53672)

Answer (score 0):

The ascx page your looking for is DisplayPost.ascx, and it's in the controls folder, and in order to modify i guess that you have to change the code in the page source and not the code behind, and to give you a hint cause i have done a lot of customization, your best option in locating any page you want to to view the page source or use the "Inspect Element" option and try to locate a control id or a css class and search for it in the entire solution until you find what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot for suggestion, I will check with DisplayPost.ascx, thanks for suggestion on locating desired page, its really tough to find pages.